# LINQ - Avoid adding empty values to HashSet

Tags: c#, .net, linq, validation

How do I avoid adding empty (`IsNullOrEmpty`) value to the list in the below linq after `p.Trim()`?

```
    HashSet<string> values;
    string[] value;
    ...  


    get { ... }
    set
    {
        value.ToList().ForEach(i => values.UnionWith(Array.ConvertAll(i.Split(';'), p => p.Trim())));
    }
```

variable declarations are for illustrative purpose only.

Comment: `value.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList().ForEach`...

Comment: You don't need to call `value.ToList().ForEach` - you can simply iterate over `value` directly or use `Select`. When using Linq, _think functionally_! (Which is to say, Linq calls should not have side-effects, which your code does because you perform `values.UnionWith`, which directly mutates the `HashSet`).

Comment: @Dai yea. good idea

Comment: @ParrishHusband Will this work for the input "abc; ;efg;"?

Comment: @JimsonKannantharaJames check out the answer by Dai, it's perfect for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I recommend avoiding using `List.ForEach`, see Eric's blog post about it here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

- You can simplify your code, you don't need to call `ToList` if you're then going to add Linq methods to the call chain because that will result in needless extra iteration through the list.
- You can also use the `HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor and simply pass-in a constructed Linq `IEnumerable<T>` (the source data will still only be iterated-over only once).
- If you just want distinct values anyway you don't need to use a `HashSet`, you can use Linq's `.Distinct()` method.
- I converted your `Array.ConvertAll(i.Split(';'), p => p.Trim())` into a `.SelectMany` call.

My approach if you just want a list of distinct strings:

```
String[] stringValues = ...
List<String> distinctValues = stringValues
    .SelectMany( v => v.Split(';') )
    .Select( v => v.Trim() )
    .Where( v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty( v ) )
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

But if you do want a `HashSet` as the final result then you can omit the `.Distinct` step (make sure you do not call `ToList`!):

```
String[] stringValues = ...
IEnumerable<String> allValues = stringValues
    .SelectMany( v => v.Split(';') )
    .Select( v => v.Trim() )
    .Where( v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty( v ) );

HashSet<String> asHashSet = new HashSet<String>( allValues );
```

If you want case-insensitive comparisons or other comparison logic use the other overloads of the `HashSet` constructor that accept a custom comparator.

Comment: Very clean approach, I like that you pass in the `IEnumerable` straight into the `HashSet`

Comment: There's no point removing duplicate values twice.  You're just constructing two different sets redundantly.

Comment: @Servy cool I didn't realize the constructor was calling `UnionWith` under the hood.

Comment: @Servy I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value.Select(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList()
      .ForEach(i => values.UnionWith(Array.ConvertAll(i.Split(';'), p => p.Trim())));
```

Comment: @ParrishHusband No man. but if you want You answer and I remove my answer

Comment: Nah, we probably both just missed the extra parenthesis :)

Comment: This won't compile because `value.Select( ... )` returns an `IEnumerable<String>` and Linq does not define a `.ForEach` extension-method for `IEnumerable` (it only exists on `List<T>`).